Configure ESLint (eslint.config.js) to only analyze TypeScript files (*.ts)
How do you use the new “flat config” file (eslint.config.js) to tell ESLint to only analyze TypeScript files (*.ts) and to use the TypeScript "strict" rules?
eslint.config.js
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default [
   ...tseslint.configs.strict,
   {
      files: ['**/*.ts'],
      rules: {
         '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
      },
   },
];

package.json
   "scripts": {
      “lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0"
   },

I kick off the lint task with the npm run lint command, but it fails because it causes ESLint to also analyze the JavaScript files in my project (and output lots of error messages).
Only the TypeScript files (*.ts) should be analyzed, and they should be analyzed with the "strict" rules.
Bonus Question:
The official ESLint documentation goes into detail on each configuration option, but I could not find a satisfactory overview of the strategy for selecting files.  The “flat config” is an array of objects, but what is the high-level flow for how files are grouped and processed through the objects?

Try ignores: ['**/*.js'] instead of files - flat config should accept it. I'm not sure you can do the same with files.

@STerliakov  I tried ignores: ['**/*.js'] instead of files: ['**/*.ts'] but still encountered the same JS errors.  I have no doubt the new "flat config" is more flexible and powerful, but judging from my googling it seems there's something unintuitive many people (including me) don't grok about it.

Well, in a ts/tsx codebase with a couple of JS files I ended up effectively updating all community rules (like [...tseslint.configs.strict.map(p => ({...p, files: ['**/*.ts']})), { /* whatever custom you have here */}] in your setup). And even merging rules ([...tseslint.configs.strict.map(p => ({...p, files: ['**/*.ts'], rules: [...p.rules, /* whatever custom you have here */]}))])

The solution below achieves:

Does not lint *.js files (important in my use case)
Avoids the tseslint.config() wrapper (I will rarely ever edit the configuration file and don't need the IDE help)
Keeps it clean and simple

eslint.config.js
import eslint   from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default [
   eslint.configs.recommended,
   ...tseslint.configs.strict,
   { ignores: ['**/*.js'] },
   {
      rules: {
         '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
      },
   },
];


See https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/typescript-eslint#config, as linked by https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started:
export default tseslint.config({
  files: ['**/*.ts'],
  extends: [
    eslint.configs.recommended,
    ...tseslint.configs.strict,
  ],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
  },
});

ESLint flat configs apply their configuration objects in order. Each config object applies to all files that are currently being linted unless they override that with a property like files. The way the OP has it introduces >=2 objects:

All of the tseslint.configs.strict objects, which apply to all configured files by default
An object that applies only to files: ['**/*.ts']

What you actually want is to include { files: ['**/*.ts'] } for all the settings. That's what tseslint.config does for you.

It looks like tseslint.config is doing magic.  Why does the files filter not work without the tseslint.config wrapper?  By the way, ">=2 objects" is because extends does not appear to be allowed without the wrapper.

Did you read the linked docs? This is answered pretty immediately on the page in https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/typescript-eslint/#flat-config-extends. It's a very small utility helper that applies settings like files and rules to everything in extends.

It’s clear you’re not able to describe the magic in your own words so you have to point to some ambiguously written documentation that I’ve already read.  Use your words.

Glad you read them - just wanted to make sure. You're right that they're a little unclear, thanks for that. Trying out different phrasing: tseslint.config takes in a config object that includes an extends array of configs to extend. It returns the equivalent ESLint config of applying the rest of the settings for each extension. Does that help? I filed a docs clarity issue on https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/9733 (I'm a maintainer on the project and co-wrote them ).

Have you tried this approach, without making use of tseslint.config ?
import js from '@eslint/js'
import tsParser from '@typescript-eslint/parser'
import tsEslintPlugin from '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint'

export default [
  ...tseslint.configs.strict,
  {
    files: ['**/*.{js,mjs,ts}']
  },
  {
    ignores: ['**/node_modules', 'dist/']
  },
  js.configs.recommended,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parser: tsParser,
    },
    plugins: {
      '@typescript-eslint': tsEslintPlugin,
    },
    rules: {
      'no-undef': 'warn',
      'no-unused-vars': 'warn',
      semi: ['error', 'never']
    }
  }
]


The answer from @Josh is correct, and helped me; but it isn't the full answer. As nicely documented in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78866363/404459, eslint will always include JavaScript files, unless explicitly ignored.  And when using tseslint.config, you need to add the excludes to a separate config object.
Try this (from the linked answer):
import eslint from '@eslint/js';
import tseslint from 'typescript-eslint';

export default tseslint.config(
  {
    ignores: [
      'dist/', // exclude specific folder
      '**/*.js', // exclude all JavaScript files
    ],
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.ts'],
    extends: [
      eslint.configs.recommended,
      ...tseslint.configs.strict,
    ],
  },
);

